# Получить потоки заданного процесса

Tags: delphi, потоки-данных

Зная процесс, нужно вывести  его потоки. Кто знает, как это реализовать? С примерчиком, если  можно, или ссылку на исходник...

Помогите, плз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть WinAPI-шная функция [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489(v=vs.85).aspx), которая делает снимок процессов. Вам останется только пробежаться по списку потоков и выбрать интересующие функциями `Thread32First` и `Thread32Next`.

Пример:

```
uses PsAPI, TlHelp32, Windows, SysUtils;

//выводит список потоков
function GetThreadsInfo(PID:Cardinal): Boolean;
  var
    SnapProcHandle: THandle;
    NextProc      : Boolean;
    ThreadEntry  : TThreadEntry32;
  begin
    SnapProcHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0); //Создаем снэпшот всех существующих потоков
    Result := (SnapProcHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    if Result then
      try
        ThreadEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(ThreadEntry);
        NextProc := Thread32First(SnapProcHandle, ThreadEntry);//получаем первый поток
        while NextProc do begin
          if ThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = PID then begin //проверка на принадлежность к процессу
              Writeln('Thread ID      ' + inttohex(ThreadEntry.th32ThreadID, 8));
              Writeln('base priority  ' + inttostr(ThreadEntry.tpBasePri));
              Writeln('delta priority ' + inttostr(ThreadEntry.tpBasePri));
              Writeln('');
          end;
          NextProc := Thread32Next(SnapProcHandle, ThreadEntry);//получаем следующий поток
        end;
      finally
        CloseHandle(SnapProcHandle);//освобождаем снэпшот
      end;
  end;
```

Получить PID своего процесса можно функцией `GetCurrentProcessId`.

---

UPD1. Путем нехитрых манипуляций с вышеозначенным кодом несложно получить функцию, возвращающую PID по названию процесса:

```
function GetPIDByName(const name: PWideChar): Cardinal;
var
  SnapProcHandle: THandle;
  ProcEntry : TProcessEntry32;
  NextProc : Boolean;
begin
  Result := 0;
  SnapProcHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  try
    ProcEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(ProcEntry);
    NextProc := Process32First(SnapProcHandle, ProcEntry);
    while NextProc do begin
      if StrComp(name, ProcEntry.szExeFile) = 0 then
        Result := ProcEntry.th32ProcessID;
      NextProc := Process32Next(SnapProcHandle, ProcEntry);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(SnapProcHandle);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: У Вас опечатка, вместо `TThreadEntry  : TThreadEntry32;` должно быть `ThreadEntry  : TThreadEntry32;`, лишняя буква `Т` в имени переменной.

Comment: @SoftR, спасибо

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, полный вид компиляции, как и что делать... а вопрос: есть процесс, нужно вывести его потоки... плс, помогите, нужно срочно...

Comment: Для консольного приложения: берете вышеуказанную функцию, и передаете ей PID процесса. Она вам выведет информацию по процессам. Если вам нужно например это в Memo отобразить, отредактируйте блок с `Writeln` соответственно.

Comment: Конкретнее? нужно из процесса найти покот и дать ему привелегии путем функции SetThreadPriority... можете выложить куда нить исходник?

Comment: такс, спс всем тут уже прогресс пошел, права выдавать могу, (тупил жестоко).. но могу только своему процессу, т.е.:
GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow, nil);
самому окну которое запущенно, как получить PID например приложения qip.exe можно с примером, и чтоб записалась в переменную??

Comment: все, смог получить PID процесса нужного =) всем спс...